# How can I write this MySQL using Laravel Query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following MySQL query and I would like to change it to the correct format for Laravel's Query builder.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(colors) FROM `cards` ORDER BY LENGTH(colors) DESC
```

This is what I currently have:

```
table('cards')
    ->orderBy(LENGTH(colors), 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I would imagine `LENGTH(colors)` would need to be in quotes, since it is a string and not a PHP function?

Comment: @halfer: Yeah, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have to use `raw` methods to be able to run SQL functions like `LENGTH()`.
This should work:

```
DB::table('cards')
    ->select('colors')
    ->distinct()
    ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(colors) DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Which one is better? orderBy(DB::raw(...)) vs orderByRaw(...)?

Comment: The result is the same so it depends which syntax you like more. I prefer `orderByRaw` because it's results in less nested parentheses  `()`

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct. You have to add ->select('colors') though. Thanks!